# How to capture movie with Gphoto2 + ffmpeg and redirect serve to html embed

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, libgphoto2

Iam trying to capture video from Panasonic DC-GH5 camera to serve this and access from browser withoud ffserver because ffserver is deprecated

Iam using Ubuntu 20.04

```
#gphoto2 -v


gphoto2         2.5.23         gcc, popt(m), exif, cdk, aa, jpeg, readline
libgphoto2      2.5.25         standard camlibs (SKIPPING lumix), gcc, ltdl, EXIF
libgphoto2_port 0.12.0         iolibs: disk ptpip serial usb1 usbdiskdirect usbscsi, gcc, ltdl, EXIF, USB, serial without locking
```

Iam try this code

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 30 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 512 -ac 1 -f alsa -i pulse -f webm -listen 1 -seekable 0 -multiple_requests 1 http://localhost:8090
```

and embed

```
<video src="http://localhost:8090"></video>
```

in index.php but don`t appear anything.
If anyone knows a way to make a server for a specific port I would appreciate it
Thank you.